# Let $n$ be any positive integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $n$ be any positive integer. Prove that there are positive integers $a$ and $b (a > b)$,
such that $10 |(n^a − n^b)$.

How would I start this proof? Would it be by induction or what?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the eleven numbers $n^0,n^1,\ldots,n^{10}$. Each of them has one of the ten numbers $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ as its last digit. Now apply the pigeonhole principle ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to watch the last digit of $n^a - n^b$ for any $n$. Hence, you just need to find the $a$ and the $b$ for $n \mod 10$

If $n \mod 10$ is $0$, $1$, $5$ or $6$, any power of $n$ will end in $0$, $1$, $5$ or, respectively $6$.

If $n \mod 10$ is $2$ then you have the following cycle of the last digit of powers of $n$: $2, 4, 8, 6, 2 \ldots$ and you can select $a = 1$, $b = 5$ for example.

Similarly for all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

a number is divisible by $10$ iff it is divisible by both $2$ and $5$. however $n^a − n^b$ is always divisible by $2$ so we need only consider divisibility by $5$. by Fermat's little theorem, for any prime $p$ we have 
$$
n^p \equiv_p n
$$
so set $p=5$

Answer (score 1):

It so happens that there exist a particular value of $a$ and a particular value of $b$,
and once you have found that $a$ and that $b$, you can prove that
$10 \mid n^a - n^b$ for any integer $n$.
You *could* use proof by induction;
this proof would not require you to examine several different cases for different
remainders when $n$ is divided by $10,$ as some other proofs would.
But you might find it difficult to guess appropriate values of $a$ and $b$
without doing computations for several different remainders, so you wouldn't
really save yourself any work.
I'd suggest one of the proofs that relies on using the value of $n$ modulo $10$
(the remainder when $n$ is divided by $10$), as explained in the other answers.